# How to format the display value of 0

Tags: matlab, octave

How to format the value of 0 in such a way that it will display "0000.000000000000" using `fprintf`? I have %8.12f but it only displays 0.000000000000.

Comment: Try looking up 'leading zeros'

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `0` character to instruct `fprintf` what the additional leading character should be, and then the width must be longer than the number of decimal places by the number of digits you wish to pad. i.e.

```
>> fprintf( '%017.12f\n', 0 )
  0000.000000000000
```